Survey on Equivariant Maps
Equivariant maps are morphisms in the category $G$-$\mathsf{Set}$. A common theme in category theory is that it is more fruitful to study the morphisms than the objects; one would assume that $G$-$\mathsf{Set}$ is no different. However, the texts I' working with (D&F, Aluffi Algebra: Chapter 0) do not seem to explore properties of equivariant maps to great depths, nor did a brief browser search turn up anything particularly relevant. Is this because they are genuinely uninteresting, or perhaps that they are not studied at an elementary level. In any case, is there any survey on equivariant maps, say about invariant properties or counting formulas that arise (which concerns only $G$-$\mathsf{Set}$, not $G$-$\mathsf{Space}$, hence no homotopy theory)?

In general, I'd argue equivariant maps are extremely important and well studied. It is just that most people study them in more specialized categories, e.g. intertwiners in representation theory, equivariant continuous maps, ...

I apologize first that I don't know any nice surveys/documents off the top of my head. But I do want to say that $G$-sets are immensely important in many fields of mathematics.
From the perspective of equivariant homotopy theory, it's of course irreplaceable and the base category in defining genuine $G$-spaces $\mathsf{An}^G$, genuine $G$-spectra $\mathsf{Sp}^G$ and multiplicative versions as certain functors out of (perhaps slightly altered versions) of the category of finite $G$-sets $\mathsf{Fin}_G$. The maps in $\mathsf{Fin}_G$ then by definition are responsible for the rich structure of the equivariant categories.
But talking about genuine $G$-spectra $\mathsf{Sp}^G$ is probably too far-reaching in a question about more basic mathematical objects. A simpler example comes to mind and as a topologist, we stay in the realm of topology.
One of the most important results in a first course in algebraic topology is the fundamental theorem of covering space theory. It's a beautiful result that classifies these topological objects through more algebraic gadgets. Unfortunately, the result is often not stated in this generality (see e.g. Munkres or Hatcher), perhaps because people want to avoid the use of categories in a first course on topology. But in my opinion it's an enlightening formulation that should not be avoided.
Theorem. Let $X$ be a nice (many connectivity assumptions) topological space and $x_0 \in X$. Then, there is an equivalence of categories
$$ \mathsf{Cov}(X) \xrightarrow{\ \simeq \ } \pi_1(X, x_0)\text{-}\mathsf{Set}, \ (p:E \to X) \mapsto (p^{-1}(x_0), \pi_1\text{-action from covering space theory}). $$
On the level of morphisms, it also restricts to the fibers.
This is nice because the complicated covering spaces now correspond to more tractable objects, namely $\pi_1$-sets! In your hope of the use of equivariant maps: By this result constructing maps of coverings correspond to constructing equivariant maps of $\pi_1$-sets. This can be easier, as the equivariant sets  can have underlying small finite sets.
